How to properly change a stream using Peerjs?
I'm using peerjs for audio calling. I want to make toggle for audio. I found out that this can be done using getSenders() and replaceTrack(). I try to do this but the remote user's stream does not change. The connection to the peer server and between the participants is successful. I can receive the remote stream.
Here's my code:
    const replaceTrackInAllCalls = (track, kind) => {
        try {
            activeCalls.forEach(call => {
                const sender = call.peerConnection.getSenders().find(s => s.track?.kind === kind);
                console.log(call.peerConnection.getSenders());
                if (sender) {
                    sender.replaceTrack(track);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    const toggleAudio = async () => {
        if (localStream.getAudioTracks().length === 0) {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
                const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
                console.log(audioTrack);
                localStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
                setLocalStream(localStream);
                replaceTrackInAllCalls(audioTrack, 'audio');
                setAudioEnabled(true);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing media devices.', error);
            }
        } else {
            localStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => {
                track.stop();
                localStream.removeTrack(track);
                replaceTrackInAllCalls(null, 'audio');
                setAudioEnabled(false);
                console.log(track);
            });
        }
    };

Or does it need to be caught somewhere else? I can provide the rest of the code with connection, call and answer if needed.
